# OpenMOLCAS error while running CCT in &CCSDT module

Tags: molecular-modeling, coupled-cluster, open-molcas

I am trying to perform a coupled cluster calculation at the CCSD(T) level using OpenMOLCAS. My input file is the following, in which I am using default values for most of the key inputs:

```
&GATEWAY
XBAS
C.STO-3G
H.STO-3G
O.STO-3G
End of basis
ZMAT
H1
C1 1 1.097
O1 2 1.343 1 111
H2 3 0.972 2 106.3 1 180
O2 2 1.202 3 124.9 4 0
End of z-matrix
&SEWARD
&SCF
 UHF
&RASSCF
  OUTOrbitals= Canonical
  LumOrb
  OUTOrbitals= Canonical
&MOTRA
  JobIph
&CCSDT
  CCT
```

Upon inspecting the output in the `.log` file, I am getting the total energy after 20 iterations:

```
      Total energy (diff) :    -186.39362934      -0.00000006
      Correlation energy  :      -0.1784309132990
      Reference energy    :    -186.2151984277011
      E1aa   contribution :       0.00000000
      E1bb   contribution :       0.00000000
      E2aaaa contribution :      -0.01326086
      E2bbbb contribution :      -0.01326086
      E2abab contribution :      -0.15190920
```

However, the code is not finishing the job correctly at the end of `&CCSDT` module. The following error message is printed to the log file:

```
Work space requirements :                17769
  Allocation of work space : Done
--- Stop Module: ccsdt at Sun Mar 10 21:07:35 2024 /rc=-6 ---
.########################.
.# Non-zero return code #.
.########################.
```

When examining the `.err` file, I am finding the following aborting signal:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7fc0cfa1f171 in ???
#1  0x7fc0cfa1e313 in ???
#2  0x7fc0cea4eb1f in ???
#3  0x7fc0cea4ea9f in ???
#4  0x7fc0cea21e04 in ???
#5  0x7fc0cea91036 in ???
#6  0x7fc0cea9819b in ???
#7  0x7fc0cea989db in ???
#8  0x7fc0cea9b55a in ???
#9  0x7fc0cea9c6cd in ???
#10  0x7fc0cfa1e608 in ???
#11  0x7fc0cfc1b047 in ???
#12  0x7fc0cfc2b03f in ???
#13  0x435762 in ???
#14  0x42146e in ???
#15  0x402460 in ???
#16  0x7fc0cea3acf2 in ???
#17  0x4024ad in ???
#18  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
```

**What could be the reason for this error, and what should I do in order to fix it?**

Comment: +1 but ideally you would provide the entire output file. If it doesn't fit within the maximum number of characters allowed in a post, then you can put it [here](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters) in a folder called 12546, which is the number in this questions URL.

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but why did you have `OUTOrbitals= Canonical` twice?

Comment: @Ihavenofreetimeanymore, I have added the files to the repo, you can check the pull request, then I will update the question here. About the  `OUTOrbitals= Canonical` I had it from the example provided in the documentation (https://molcas.gitlab.io/OpenMolcas/sphinx/tutorials/tut_ccsdt.html?highlight=outorbitals%20canonical), I checked the case when it is mentioned only once and I found no difference in the output .

Answer (score 6):

I have run a calculation with that input file, and can see that an error occurred when trying to calculate the (T) part of the CCSD(T) calculation, as you can see that we have `************************` instead of a real number:

```
       CCSD     =      -186.3936292872034
       T3 corr. =************************
       CCSD + T3=************************
  T3 energy decomposition into spin parts
  Eaaa =  -1320133193.83886
  Eaab =  -851388296422.193
  Eabb =   1505020301064.51
  Ebbb =   24408709436.1437


      Happy Landing!

--- Stop Module: ccsdt at Sun Mar 10 13:19:14 2024 /rc=-1 --
```

The next hint that I see, is that you have a "return code" of `rc=-1`. In my case, the `.err` file says nothing except for:

```
double free or corruption (!prev)
```

which is very different from your `.err` file, so we are probably using slightly different compilers, since the CCSD(T) code in OpenMolcas probably didn't change much between my version, which is the `openmolcas/20.10` module on Compute Canada's machines, which have the following settings:

```
Host name: build-node.computecanada.ca (Linux)
C Compiler ID: Intel
C flags: -O2 -march=core-avx2 -axCore-AVX512 -ftz -fp-speculation=safe -fp-model source -std=gnu99 -qopenmp
Fortran Compiler ID: Intel
Fortran flags: -O2 -march=core-avx2 -axCore-AVX512 -ftz -fp-speculation=safe -fp-model source  -fpp -i8 -r8 -heap-arrays -qopenmp
Definitions: _MOLCAS_;_I8_;_LINUX_;_GA_;_MOLCAS_MPP_;SCALAPACK;_MKL_;_FDE_
Parallel: ON (GA=ON)
```

Ideally you would have included the entire output file, along with the entire input file and `.err` file, so that we could see more output data (such as the `************************` that I showed, and the version and compiler information. I have saved your input file as `inp.inp`, and all of the output that I included in this answer, can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters/tree/master/12546) in the `.log` and `.err` files, which are complete.